# How to fix java.lang.ClassCastException in Java

Tags: hibernate, casting, classcastexception

I use version 3.x of hibernate and i have an object X that inherits from a parent object Y. and i have another object Z which has a relation with the object X as follows  `X OneToMany Z`. So the object Z will contain the object X.

I read a lot of questions but it does not answer my problem.

In my XHTML i chose the X object in a dropdown and I retrieve its id to load the object and in my bean i retrieve this ID to load the X object the insertion is done by inserting the object X with null value. when I try to display if the object has been recovered by calling my service this error appears

```
An Error Occurred:

java.lang.ClassCastException: ma.controle.gestion.modele.Parent_$$_javassist_6 cannot be cast to ma.controle.gestion.modele.Activite
```

Here is The parent object ( Y )

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE_OBJET")
@DiscriminatorValue("PARENT")
public class Parent implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long idt_parent;
private String nom;
private String description;
// Getters Setters
}
```

Here is the Object which inherits from Y ( X )

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ACTIVITE")
public class Activite extends Parent implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String code_sa;

// The mapping of the object Z

@OneToMany(mappedBy="activite",cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE,  orphanRemoval = true)
private Collection<Affectation_Activite> affectation_Activites;

// Getters , setters and construct

}
```

Here is the modele ( Object Z )

```
@Entity
public class Affectation_Activite implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long idt_affectation_activite;
private Date dateDebut;
private Date dateFin;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idt_parent")
private Activite activite;


// Getters, setters and construct 
}
```

And here is the fucntion save of my bean

```
public void save(ActionListener e){




    Activite activite=(Activite)parentService.findParentById(idt_parent);


    System.out.println("Activite nom ====> " + activite .getNom() + " et la description" + activite.getDescription() );

    affectationActivite.setActivite(activite);

    affectationActiviteService.addAffectation(affectationActivite);


}
```

Comment: I think that this is because as you are using the parent service it is returning a new parent without the values of the Active class. You should use Active service instead

Comment: @ronce96 thank you for ur response, but should I create for each son their service? Is it a good method?

Comment: Could you post the implementation of your findParentById() method?

Comment: @ronce96 Here is my service `@Override
 public Parent findParentById(Long id) {
  return parentDao.load(id);
 }` and i use the genericDao 

  `public T load(PK id) {
     return (T) getHibernateTemplate().load(type, id);
     }`

Comment: Are you using the entityManager class in your parentDao? Take a look at this http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/retrieve

Comment: @ronce96 no i'm using SessionFactory I add activiteService and it works. But I would like to know is what there is a good practice

Comment: I think that the best practice will be to make a service class for Parent and other for Activite as long as you may need some operations in one class that you dont need in the other. Imagine that you want to make a findBy code_sa, you will implement it in the activite service and not in the parent, so I will use one service for each class

Comment: As an adition if you use the entityManager you have to specify the id and the class of the instance that you want to find. In your case if you want to find a Parent object but the id belongs to Activite class row it will raise an exception as long the discrimimator column does not match with the discriminator value of the class that you want

Comment: If this comments where helpfull I appreciate the up vote.

Comment: @ronce96 thanks for these informations, i appreciate your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : I think that this is because as you are using the parent service it is returning a new parent without the values of the Active class. You should use Active service instead

Related to @Ronce96